# Is there a difference in continuity between a function having range $\subseteq \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ and codomain $\subseteq \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

What I'm about to ask and/or say may be horribly wrong, but I feel there some subtlety to this topic that I don't really get right now.

Suppose you wonder whether there is a nonconstant continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ and the answer is quickly decided to be no: the Intermediate Value Theorem would forbid this because if $f(x_0) < f(x_1)$ for $x_0\neq x_1$ and  $x_0,x_1\in [a,b]$ then $f$ must obtain every output between $f(x_0)$ and $f(x_1)$ for some input and thus output some rational numbers.

**However**, this argument seems to me to essentially suppose that $f$'s codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ and so IVT shows that being nonconstant violates a fundamental property of continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ but *perhaps* there could be a nonconstant function which is continuous and its codomain is $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$.

To illustrate clearer what I mean:

One way of seeing the above result is to recall the fact that the image of any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ under a continuous map is also compact. If the image of $[a,b]$ had been, say, $[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]\cap (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})$, then we'd have a contradiction as this image is *not* closed and thus not compact. However, this set *is both closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$* and so if $f$'s codomain really is $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ (and not simply $\mathbb{R}$ with its range being a subset of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$) then this argument on its own doesn't work.

**Question: Does any of this make sense? Can continuity essentially depend on what you consider to be the codomain?**

Comment: No, the definition of continuity makes no reference to the codomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question in bold: **no**, continuity does not depend of the codomain (in a sense which is formalized in the next paragraph). But this made sense, it was a valid question to ask even if it was not exactly formal.

If $f \colon A \to B$ is continuous and $B \subset C$ then so is the composition $f \colon A \to B \xrightarrow{\mathbf{inc}} C$, if $B$ is a subspace of $C$. Likewise, if $f \colon A \to C$ is continuous, so is its corestriction. I can sketch some proofs if needed.

Also, as a side remark: the intermediate value theorem is actually a theorem about connectedness, not compactness. It is a special case of the fact that continuous functions send connected sets to connected sets (in $\Bbb R$ these are always intervals). This bypasses your issue: since the connected components of $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ are singletons and $[a,b]$ is connected, we have $f([a,b]) = \{c\}$ for some $c$.

Comment: Don't worry it didn't come across as rude at all :) Might I ask what the "correstriction" of f is?

Comment: Sure: if $f \colon A  \to C$ is a function and $\mathbf{im} \ f \subset B \subset C$, we can define the corestriction $f|^B \colon A \to B$ as the "same" function with codomain $B$. This is a different function, but it does not modify continuity. Also, there was an extra 'r' there, I switched languages but only half-way :p Sometimes the prefix "co" indicates some type of duality, in this case, this refers to the dual notion of restriction (when we consider a smaller domain).

Comment: If B is a subset of the image of f, how does this work? What happens to points $x\in A$ s.t. $f(x)\notin B$?

Comment: Oh, my bad! I am making too many typos. Indeed, it just doesn't, I wrote that the wrong way. Fixed it now. Precisely, the condition is the bare minimum to guarantee $f(x) \in B$, i.e. $\mathbf{im} \ f \subset B$, as you correctly point out.

Comment: I just thought I'd add that the key point of where I went wrong is this: my thinking was that compactness of images of compact sets was the important thing and that compactness *is* affected by the choice of a wider space. However, in the example which served to illustrate my intuition the key property of closedness actually coincided with the really important property I should have been focussed on: connectedness. Crucially, *connectedness does not change with choice of a larger "containing space"*. Just thought this summary was somewhat useful (if only to me!).